# How to create email addresses using an array of existing names?

Tags: c

I have a sample of a base code below (names are in CSV format, first and last name are separated by a comma) that I am going to use to make email addresses.

So, the goals are: 1. Using 3 characters from first and second name, create an email address adding +gmail.com (e.g markas@gmail.com). 
2. Use only lowercase characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STR 50

void PrintPerson(char person[]);


int main(void)
{
    char data[][MAX_STR] = {"Maria,Kask",
                            "Johanna-Maria,Kask",
                            "Kalev Kristjan,Kask"};
    int i;
    int numOfPeople = sizeof(data) / MAX_STR;

    printf("Number of people: %d\n", numOfPeople);
    for (i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++)
    {
        PrintPerson(data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void PrintPerson(char person[])
{
    printf("Parsing: '%s'\n", person);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't sound too difficult. I assume it is homework, so I'll just give you an outline:

Make a function that receives a name and a buffer for the output, e.g.

```
int toEmail(char *name, char *email);
```

The function returns whether it was able to create an email adress from the name.

The function takes the first three characters of the name and copies them to `email`, using the `tolower` function.

Then it skips until it finds a comma and then copies the next three characters to `email` using the `tolower` function. If it doesn't find a comma it returns `0` to indicate an error.

Then it appends the `"@gmail.com"` string and returns `1` to indicate success.

Now in `main` have an array like your `data` for the `email` addresses and pass each element of `data` and of `email` in a loop to the function.

Now you are done.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right :) Thanks, helped a lot!